# "*.foo" shell function

Tags: zsh, sh, zshrc

I want to add to my .zshrc function that will perform operations with file that has ".c" suffix. For example,

```
*.c () {
    gcc $0 -o ${0%.*}
}
```

must perform "gcc foo.c -o foo" when I am entering "foo.c"

But when I added this function to ".zshrc", my shell begins prints "no matches found: *.c" on login.

Can I do this other way or make this function "lazy"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want `alias -s` behaviour. From the manpages:

```
 ALIASES
   Suffix aliases are supported in zsh since version 4.2.0. Some examples:

       alias -s tex=vim
       alias -s html=w3m
       alias -s org=w3m

   Now pressing return-key after entering foobar.tex starts vim with foobar.tex. Calling
   a html-file runs browser w3m. www.zsh.org and pressing enter starts w3m with argument
   www.zsh.org.
```

Combine your written function to a suffix alias and you should be set to go!

First, write your function in this form:

```
compile_c () {     
   gcc $1 -o ${1%.*}
}
```

And then the suffix alias

```
alias -s c='compile_c'
```

will work as intended.

Comment: It ain't work because $0, $1, $2 variables are not defined in alias

Comment: @user123980801 I think this is what progo meant: `__gcc_compile () { gcc $1 -o ${1%.*} }; alias -s c=__gcc_compile` - This works for me with zsh 4.3.11.